# Edit RGB values in an image dependant on each pixel's red value

Tags: python

What I want to do is take every pixel of an image and make the green and blue values match the red value of each pixel.

I've tried converting to black and white in Paint.net but it averages the RGB values and doesn't give me the right shades of black/grey.

I've just started learning Python and I don't know where to start for something like this. I would think there's a different program that would let me do this but I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: I suggest taking a look at `Pil` or python imaging library, there should be lots of tutorial out there

Comment: If you do this with a matrix of `1,0,0,0` , `1,0,0,0` , `1,0,0,0` you'll get what you want https://stackoverflow.com/a/56323081/2836621

Comment: "I've just started learning Python and I don't know where to start for something like this." **Don't**; learn the fundamentals of Python first, before attempting your own projects. Practically speaking, you will need third-party libraries in order to "load" images into a form that can be manipulated within the Python code. In most cases you will want to use Numpy to *represent* that data. Neither of these things will be properly understandable to you without getting the background knowledge first.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```py
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO
response = requests.get('https://www.ricoh-imaging.co.jp/english/products/q-s1/ex/img/bod_mainImg_01.jpg')
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content)).resize((400, 300)).convert('RGB') # make sure to be in RGB format
img
```

[image]

Then the convert to a numpy array and you can easily copy the red (0) channels to green and blue channels (1 and 2).

```py
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(img)
arr[:,:,1] = arr[:,:,0]
arr[:,:,2] = arr[:,:,0]
Image.fromarray(arr)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes I think it is spoon feeding, the OP admitted to be starting with python, so I think it is fair to give a complete working example. Probably they will still have to figure out how to install the required pages.

Comment: @CunningBard You make it sound like a crime to provide a high quality, comprehensive, complete and tested answer. Personally, I think such things are to be encouraged and upvoted rather than poorly-researched, incomplete answers that don't adress the question or really help show actual, working code.

Comment: You can just do `Image.fromarray(arr).save('result.png')` to save on disk.

Comment: @MarkSetchell the problem is that, given the steps that need to be taken, the implied question is far too broad. Spoon feeding is not *wrong*, but questions need to be focused, and OP needs to learn more in order to make it *possible to ask* properly focused questions (and do research into them). Copying and pasting this code does not teach anything. Keep in mind that OP *didn't even ask* about the problem of downloading an image from the Internet. Will it really be clear to someone "just learning Python" how to adapt the code to other circumstances, or how it works?

Comment: How is this supposed to be comprehensive for a beginner? If you don't know how to handle libraries, this plain won't work. Opening the image is just arcane and not obvious how one would open an image from another source. The trailing `img` doesn't make sense unless run in the correct environment. The numpy stuff is going to be unobvious even to people who are familiar with Python but don't use it for image/numpy tasks. This Q&A *could* be useful for beginners, but in this state it is just cargo cult; please [edit] to add the background and references needed to understand and use the code.